# onos service start error - ONOS GUI not ready yet... please stand by

Tags: user-interface, networking, sdn, openflow, onos

After changing the IP address of my machine, I'm encountering an issue with the ONOS GUI service. When attempting to start the GUI, I receive the message "ONOS GUI not ready yet... please stand by." I've restarted the service, but the problem exists.
when I run opt/onos/bin/onos -l onos from the onos CLI, I get the warning "WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!"  how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the known-hosts directory resolved my issue with ONOS CLI connection establishment.

also, I had initially installed it in the wrong way.